# how can I make selectable rows work on Vuetify 2.0 datatables with ssr pagination?

Tags: datatable, vuetify.js

I hope everyone's fine

I'm trying to make the show-select feature work on Vuetify 2.0.x datatables with SSR pagination, with no luck at all.

We were working on vuetify 1.5.x up until now and we changed since it was troubling in there too.

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/JullietV/pen/jOWqmyB)

I'm just using `show-select` docs are not further specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed item-key="unique column name" in v-data-table

here is the codepen
https://codepen.io/manojkmishra/pen/OJMNjzq?editors=1010

Template part

```
 <v-app id="inspire">
 <div>
   {{msg}}
  <v-data-table show-select v-model="selected"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :options.sync="options"
    :items-per-page="5"
    :server-items-length="totalDesserts"
    :loading="loading"
    class="elevation-1"
    item-key="name"
  ></v-data-table>
  </div>
  </v-app>
```

Script part

```
<script>

export default {
data () {
return { selected: [],
  totalDesserts: 0,
  desserts: [],
  loading: true,
  options: {},
  headers: [
    {
      text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
      align: 'start',
      sortable: false,
      value: 'name',
    },
    { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
    { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
    { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
    { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
    { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
  ],
}
},
watch: {
options: {
  handler () {
    this.getDataFromApi()
      .then(data => {
        this.desserts = data.items
        this.totalDesserts = data.total
      })
  },
  deep: true,
},
},
computed: {
msg() {
  console.log('msg-',this.selected)
  return this.selected
}
```

},
    mounted () {

```
this.getDataFromApi()
  .then(data => {
    this.desserts = data.items
    this.totalDesserts = data.total
  })
},
methods: {
getDataFromApi () {
  this.loading = true
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const { sortBy, sortDesc, page, itemsPerPage } = this.options

    let items = this.getDesserts()
    const total = items.length

    if (sortBy.length === 1 && sortDesc.length === 1) {
      items = items.sort((a, b) => {
        const sortA = a[sortBy[0]]
        const sortB = b[sortBy[0]]

        if (sortDesc[0]) {
          if (sortA < sortB) return 1
          if (sortA > sortB) return -1
          return 0
        } else {
          if (sortA < sortB) return -1
          if (sortA > sortB) return 1
          return 0
        }
      })
    }

    if (itemsPerPage > 0) {
      items = items.slice((page - 1) * itemsPerPage, page * itemsPerPage)
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.loading = false
      resolve({
        items,
        total,
      })
    }, 1000)
  })
},
getDesserts () {
  return [
    {
      name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
      calories: 159,
      fat: 6.0,
      carbs: 24,
      protein: 4.0,
      iron: '1%',
    },
    {
      name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
      calories: 237,
      fat: 9.0,
      carbs: 37,
      protein: 4.3,
      iron: '1%',
    },

  ]
},
},
}

</script>
```